# Log output of date and ansiweather on the same line

Tags: shell, logging, io-redirection

I installed ansiweather on my macOS, and I want to log the weather a few times per day using a cronjob.

This is my code:

```
date +%Y-%m-%d--%H:%M && ansiweather -l  Amsterdam,NL -s true -h false -p false >> test.txt
```

When I view my `test.txt` file, I only see the ansiweather results, and not the date.

I want to have a log file that shows the date [space] [ansiweather details] on each line.

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's replace your commands with dummy commands:

```
$ echo 1 && echo 2 >> out.txt
1
```

This prints the output of the first command to standard output, and the output of the second command is redirected to `out.txt`.

To get them both redirected, group them:

```
{ echo 1 && echo 2; } >> out.txt
```

That's only half the solution, though; `out.txt` will contain

```
1
2
```

on separate lines.

To get the output on a single line, you can use `printf`:

```
printf '%s %s\n' "$(echo 1)" "$(echo 2)" >> out.txt
```

resulting in `out.txt` containing

```
1 2
```

Applied to your actual command:

```
printf '%s %s\n' \
    "$(date '+%F--%R')" \
    "$(ansiweather -l  Amsterdam,NL -s true -h false -p false)" >> test.txt
```

Notice that `+%Y-%m-%d--%H:%M` can be abbreviated to `'%F--%R'` (at least with GNU `date` and the stock macOS `date`; POSIX doesn't require either `%F` or `%R`).

Comment: That's wow, that is a very clear explanation, it makes perfect sense now. And it Works! Thank you very much for taking the time to explain this!